# Pandas: repeat dataframe n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

This is probably quite simple, but I'm new to pandas. I need to repeat a dataframe n times. My current dataframe looks like:

```
df =

0    0
1    60
2    300
3    320
```

For example, for n=3, my desired output is:

```
new_df =

0    0
1    60
2    300
3    320
4    0
5    60
6    300
7    320
8    0
9    60
10   300
11   320
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
N = 3
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    col
0     0
1    60
2   300
3   320
4     0
5    60
6   300
7   320
8     0
9    60
10  300
11  320
```